# How to specify URL params in Plunker for Angular JS routing?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, plunker

Now I have Angular JS example with rouring:

How I can specify URL params in Plunker that to check that? I mean to so something like: `/test/4` Working example:

```
[http://plnkr.co/edit/ChMaiougIW4KiNNkUTlO?p=preview][1]
```

Comment: simple enough to use an anchor tag with an href

Comment: Can you demonstrate exmaple, please?

Comment: `<a href="#/text/page">Go to test</a>` ... not complicated

Comment: Do you mean to add html code with link in template on plunker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two changes are required:

In **app.js**, you need to configure `$locationProvider` for `html5Mode`:

```
app.config(['$locationProvider',
  function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider
      .html5Mode(true)
      .hashPrefix('!');
  }
])
```

In **index.html**, you need to make your links relative, using `html5Mode` like: `<a href="test/oleg">Go to test</a>`.

Angular will rewrite the href if the browser doesn't support `pushState`.